# Logical Stacking and Missing Data on R

Tags: r, logic

I have a data frame where questions are logically stacked. Using the R program, how do i loop to find missing data, considering those logics

For example
My data frame looks like this:

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqyO0.png)

Here, I want to differentiate between the NAs that are truly NA, because the question does not apply to them (if they play any sport other than soccer) and the NAs that are missing data. I.e. 2nd entry (highlighted) - participant plays soccer but did not answer how many times per week. How do i code that on R?

Comment: Depending on what your next uses are you could perhaps change them to -1?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new variable which distinguishes the two types of missing values.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(missing_type = case_when(is.na(times) & sport == "soccer" ~ "missing",
                                  is.na(times) & sport != "soccer" ~ "N/A",
                                  TRUE ~ "not_missing"))
```